# Is there a way to take lower/higher values based on trend?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a data frame that contains three columns id, date, and value which looks like this.

| ID | Date | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2022-04-05 | 100 |
| ABC | 2023-02-04 | 200 |
| ABC | 2023-02-04 | 300 |
| ABC | 2023-05-10 | 400 |
| ABC | 2023-06-27 | 250 |
| ABC | 2023-06-27 | 200 |

I want something like this:

| ID | Date | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2022-04-05 | 100 |
| ABC | 2023-02-04 | 300 |
| ABC | 2023-05-10 | 400 |
| ABC | 2023-06-27 | 200 |

Is possible to do this? Here, If there are two or more values on the same date and then compare it with the previous date and if the value is increased then take the maximum from all values on that date and if it was decreased then take the minimum. Also, there will not be any case where one value will be lower and one value will be higher than the previous date value. So, If any date has 2 or more values then it all will either be higher or lower than the previous date value.

Comment: What do you mean if the value increases? Do you mean the total value of today is larger than total value of yesterday?

Comment: If the value always is increased or decreased , not unordered, just use `drop_duplicates` with `keep='last'` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple code snippet does what you are requesting. Keep in mind that there can be cases where the vals for a data can be both below and above the previous date's values. This is of course not accounted for.

```
data = [{"id":"ABC", "Date":"2022-04-05","val":100},
        {"id":"ABC", "Date":"2023-02-04","val":200},
        {"id":"ABC", "Date":"2023-02-04","val":300},
        {"id":"ABC", "Date":"2023-05-10","val":400},
        {"id":"ABC", "Date":"2023-06-27","val":250},
        {"id":"ABC", "Date":"2023-06-27","val":200}]

prev_date = data[0]["Date"] #Used to keep track of date and see if it changes

prev_value = 0 #Used to keep track of the chosen value from last date

current_values = [] #Used to keep track of all values from current date

new_data = [] #This will have the new data with the schema provided

for x, entry in enumerate(data): #Goes through all entries
    if prev_date == entry["Date"] and x != len(data)-1: #Check it the date remains the same and makes sure we are not at the end of the list
        current_values.append(entry["val"])
    else:
        if (x == len(data)-1): #In case we are at the end of the list we need to update current_values with our last entry
            if prev_date == entry["Date"]:
                current_values.append(entry["val"])
            else:
                current_values = [entry["val"]]

        if any(current_value > prev_value for current_value in current_values): #Checks if the new date's values are higher or lower than last recorded value
            prev_value = max(current_values)
        else:
            prev_value = min(current_values)

        current_values = [entry["val"]] #New date's val is saved for future comparison
        new_data.append({"id":data[x-1]["id"], "Date":data[x-1]["Date"],"val":prev_value}) #Save data
        prev_date = entry["Date"]#Save current date
print(new_data)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting "Type Error:Invalid argument, not a string or column: [100] of type . For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function"   at prev_value = max(current_values) command. Also, I have very huge data frame with many different ids so I think I have to loop through that as well.